# Python3の配列操作　指定したインデックスの配列を作りたい。

Tags: python, array

Python3の配列操作について質問させてください。

指定したインデックスの配列を作りたいのですが、どうしてよいか分かりません。

配列Aから配列Aの3,6,9番目で構成する配列Bを作成したいのですが、良いアイディアをお持ちの方はおられませんか？

配列A =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

配列B=[4,7,10]

なるべく,Forやappendなどは使わない方法で一括で行いたいのですが・・・

delやpopで複数の範囲を扱えるといいのにな。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 3*n 番目の要素を取り出すという事であれば、 `B=A[3::3]` で良いかと。

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。例として記述しましたが、n+3の倍数のインデックスではありません。もう少し良い例をお示しするべきでした。

Comment: では `idx = [3, 6, 9]` として、`list(map(A.__getitem__, idx))` はどうでしょうか。

Comment: より適切な例や、`for`を使いたくない理由があるようなので、質問を編集して、それらの情報を追加することをお勧めします。

Answer (score 2):

すでに解説されている[スライス](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B9#slicings)でうまくいかない場合は「一括」といえるか解りませんが、[内包表記](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)があります。質問の例ですと以下のようになります。

```
# [元のリスト[i] for i in 抜き出すインデックスたち]

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [a[i] for i in (3, 6, 9)]
print(b)
# => [4, 7, 10]
```

（日本語で「n番目」というと曖昧さがあるので注意が必要だと思います。Python などは最初の要素のインデックスが 0 ですが、日本語ではそれを「1番目」と言うことも多いのではないでしょうか）

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。 質問にあるように、できればforを使いたくないのですが・・・・ なんかPythonのループ処理って異常に重いですよね・・

Comment: @rock  シビアな性能上の問題を抱えている場合は、ます[プロファイラ](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/profile.html)で現状を測定し、どの程度の性能の向上を目指すのか定量的に決定することが必要です。数パーセントの話であれば、使用する構文の変更や、ループ内でのグローバル変数への参照の削除など、細かな対策で可能かも知れません。何倍もの性能向上を目指すなら、別の手段が必要でしょう。

Answer (score 0):

> Forやappendなどは使わない方法で一括で行いたい

Forやappendを使わないで任意の配列を取り出したいならこれで良いのでは。

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,8,7,8,9,10]
b = [a[3],a[6],a[9]]
print(b)
#=> [4,7,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator.itemgetter` で実現できます。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

```
In [1]: A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [2]: B = [4,7,10]

In [3]: from operator import itemgetter

In [4]: list(itemgetter(3, 6, 9)(A))
Out[4]: [4, 7, 10]
```